# What exactly is modulo 64

Tags: modulo

I haven't found any specific links on the net that explain what exactly modulo 64 is. I'm no programmer but came across this while studying a 3GPP2 CDMA2000 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modulo is the remainder of division of one number by another. So, a **modulo 64** of a number is the remainder of this number divided by 64. For instance, the **modulo 64** of 65 is 1, as when you divide 65 by 64, the remainder is 1.

Comment: Is it similar to an xor of the two numbers